# How to store an html form element in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have 3 html range slider fields on a page, and I would like to store their values in a cookie, so that the sliders will hold the data the user selected when they scroll away from the page and and come back later. I need to keep it stored for like 3 hours or so.

```
<input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000">
<input type="range" id="period" name="period" min="1" max="15">
<input type="range" id="earn" name="earn" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000">
```

*I am very new to javascript & php. I have googled for tutorials, but the samples I've seen looks more complicated than what I need.*

Answer (score 4):

This should work. The two functions should allow you to set cookies by name/value/time and get them back by name. Since you asked for three hours, I have done a 3*60*60*1000 to get the milliseconds to set the cookie for. You can change it as required.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, time) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + time);
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

setCookie('loan',document.getElementById('loan').value,10800000);

getCookie('loan');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - it seems to be what I need. I don't 100% understand how to fully implement it though. I assume I place it in <script> tags in the head? Do I need to do anything else to make it work?

Comment: Yes place these in script tags in the head and use the functions anywhere. You might have to modify them to set the cookies onChange of the fields.

Comment: Ok thanx for your help. I have been reading more about cookies online. Do I need to use some sort of an if function to check if the cookie exists so the html elements can show the saved value of the cookie, and if it doesn't exist, it needs to go back to the default?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, you use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this:

```
<input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000">
<input type="range" id="period" name="period" min="1" max="15">
<input type="range" id="earn" name="earn" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000">

//When you want to save values in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('loan', document.getElementById("loan").value );
localStorage.setItem('period', document.getElementById("period").value );
localStorage.setItem('earn', document.getElementById("earn").value );

//When you want to access already stored values:
var loan = localStorage.getItem('loan');
var period = localStorage.getItem('period');
var earn = localStorage.getItem('earn');
```

You will get `null` for the first time you try to access these properties i.e. when you do not have these values stored in your 'localStorage'. You may need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` depending on your needs, as the values returned here would be in `String` format.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the entire form to a string with `innerHTML`, and then save that string.

Example (for the entire form):

```
var stringToCookie = document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML;
```

But you lost JavaScript modifications, events, etc...